# Installing LEX/YACC or flex/bison on Windows, Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, yacc

There's too much bytes and too few information in Internet, so I decided to ask if someone have already done such an installation.

1. How to compile/where to download
   binaries?
2. Where can I find a build
   rule?
3. Where can I find a bunch of
   good samples (with associativity
   resolution, symbol tables etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get flex and bison as part of cygwin, then reference them in visual studio.

This has more detail:
http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronmar/archive/2004/10/13/242004.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There are new versions of flex&bison for windows without extra dependencies at http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison